# How to simulate gyroscope feeds in IOS?

Tags: ios, ipad, ios-simulator, gyroscope

I have iPad first generation. But I should develop an application which requires gyroscope sensor feeds. How can I simulate gyroscope like I am rotating my iPad?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think we can do this.
If we could, then what is the point of implementing a gyroscope in iPhone4/4s and iPad in the first place?
If you accept an imperfect simulation, you can use the accelerometer to detect the rotation based on one axis only. Say for example, you put iPad with the monitor facing up (so now the y-axis is horizontal), now if you rotate iPad along with y-axis, you can detect the rotation with the changes of x and z values.

Answer (score 2):

I've created a sensor simulator for iOS. You can check it out [here](https://github.com/nmarkovic04/Phoney).